# Why GPU memory usage is increasing when I call a method that uses tensors already exist on GPU?

Tags: python, memory, time, pytorch, gpu

Consider the following overviews of two codes in PyTorch. Dataloader and all other aspects are the same for the two codes except the `extra_class`, which is present in some other module.

**Code #1:**

```
main(args)
......
train(nn)
......
```

**Code #2:**

```
main(args)
......
object = extra_class(...arguments...)       #creating object
train(nn)
object.method1()                           #calling method on object
......
```

**Extra class in another module**

```
extra_class(...parameters......)
    __init__(...):
         tensor1.to(device)  # using a lot of `.to(device)` on tensors
         tensor2.to(device) 
         ..................
   method1() { .... }  # using the tensors that are transferred to device in __init__()
```

When I run **code #1**, then there is a constant usage of GPU memory (say 70%). But when I run **code #2**, while *executing* the line `object.method1()`, the memory of GPU is increasing suddenly and after the line, it is decreasing. So, I can safely infer that the line is loading many tensors into GPU memory during execution, which is causing an increase in executing time. But I am not understanding why it is happening.

I am not using `.to(device)` in `method1` of  `extra_class`. The `method1` is only using the tensors that are transferred to the GPU device in `__init__()` of `extra_class` only. **So all the transfers have to be done during object creation only** ( `object = extra_class(...arguments...)`) if I am correct, but why the transfer is happening when I call the `method1` on the object?

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue caused due not [detaching](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.detach.html) a heavy tensor that is passed to the method.

If you do not detach the inputs from the computational graph in PyTorch, then it will construct a graph containing that variable also.